# Key value table to json in BigQuery

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

**Hey all,**

I have a table that looks like this:

| row | key | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 100 |
| 2 | b | 200 |
| 3 | c | "apple |
| 4 | d | {} |

I want to convert it into JSON:

```
{
    "a": 100,
    "b": 200,
    "c": "apple",
    "d": {}
}
```

Note: the number of lines can change so this is only an example

Thx in advanced !

Comment: **val** column should be **string** type, but expected json has different data types for each value of key like json number, string and object.  Do you want to infer the data type of it dynamically and conver it into json ?

Comment: I think In my case its all strings any way

Answer (score 1):

With string manipulation,

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 'a' key, '100' value UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', '200' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c', '"apple"' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'd', '{}'
)
SELECT '{' || STRING_AGG(FORMAT('"%s": %s', key, value)) || '}' json
  FROM sample_table;
```

You can get following result similar to your expected output.

[image]

Comment: Thx for your answer, the idea is not to query every row because the number of lines can change